# Find changes in imported data daily

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I have a workbook that pulls data from a website and changes daily.  I would like to know what has changed from day to day (or even week to week).  Is there any way to do this?

I'm using the IMPORTHTML function, so the sheet doesn't necessarily change, but the data does. I would like a snapshot of the data every so often, compare it to the previous day's data and then publish the differences in a separate sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/142cUO14r17xEdVhdStRWcXJJdMwiI0x6rMKWGD9HPcA/edit#gid=47319349

I searched through this forum, but couldn't find anything relevant to my needs.

Comment: The linked spreadsheet has a lot of sheets and it's easy to figured out that IMPORTHTML was used. By the other hand, as the spreadsheet could be modified, deleted or unshared to the public, all the relevante details should be included on the question.

Answer (score 0):

- go to your sheet
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`LEFT ALT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`H`</kbd>**
- and on the right panel you can see daily, hourly even minute changes

  [image: 0]

Comment: This is nice, but I'm not looking for changes that I or anyone else makes to the sheet, I'm looking for differences in the dynamic data from day to day.  I'm using the IMPORTHTML function, so the sheet doesn't necessarily change, but the data does.  I would like a snapshot of the data every so often, compare it to the previous day's data and then publish the differences in a separate sheet.

Comment: @JeffTrujillo This details should be included on the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare the data daily, you should copy the data somewhere.

- The basic alternative is to do it manually.
- Another alternative is to use Google Apps Script to create a time-driven trigger to call a script that makes the copy of the data.

Once the data of two o more days is stored on the spreadsheet you could use conditional format to compare. If the data is on different sheets, you should use custom formula using INDIRECT for the references.

Another way is to use Google Apps Script to compare the data and do something (apply a format, make a report, etc.)